# [innerHtml]: String with left angle bracket

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Why does Angular [innerHtml] remove text going after the left angle bracket?

I have a line with HTML content, for example:

```
text1 <text2 <a>link</a>
```

the result will be:

```
text1 link
```

and the link is not clickable.

The result I want is:

```
text1 <text2 link
```

with a clickable link.

If I use string like this

```
text1 < text2 <a>link</a>
```

The result is what I expect.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Please add code

Comment: What does your browser render if you give it an HTML file containing only the mentioned string? What does it render if you replace the first `<` with `&lt;`?

Comment: I think even with `<` will be the same result. have you give `<a>` a `href` property?

Comment: If i place `&lt;` instead first `<` I get result like this - **text1 <text2 [link](http://google.com)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's nothing to do with Angular, it's the normal behaviour of HTML.
You can't open a tag like `<text` without closing it.

If you want that to work you have to escape it :

```
   text = "text1 &lt;text2 <a href=''>link</a>"
```

> [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hb8fyiAfoujC0FV9Qtxj?p=info)

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think about symbol HTML name!